# Contact Form 7 - Issues with wpcf7_before_send_mail and wpcf7_submit

Tags: php, wordpress, hook, contact-form-7

I am currently working on a site that has users submit through a form created with Contact Form 7. I am trying to expand this to recording that activity (date/time, logged in user, grabbing information from the fields filled), and I have tried a number of times and ways to use both the hooks wpcf7_before_send_mail and wpcf7_submit but neither seem to be working. The form submits, but the code the code below does not run. I have even attempted manually entering the infomation (table name, user id, customer, etc) manually to see if it would submit and it still does not.

Below is the current code that I am using to save some information to the data base I want the activity stored in:

```
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'save_in_database');

function save_in_database($data) {
    global $wpdb;
    $account_number = get_account_number();
    $department = get_user_role();

    if ($data->title == 'Social_Media_Tool_Form'){
        $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
        if ( $submission ) {
            $cf7_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
            $name = $cf7_data['customer-name'];
        }
    }


    $activity_table_name = $wpdb->prefix .'_'. $account_number . '_activity_log';

    //Creates activity log
    $wpdb->insert($activity_table_name, array(
        'date'              =>  current_time('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'user_id'           =>  get_current_user_id(),
        'customer_name'     =>  $name,
        'activity_type'     =>  'social',
        'department'        =>  $department
    ));
}
```

I've used this same code to record other activities prior, so in theory, it should be working here.

I'm currently on Wordpress 5.1 and using Contact Form 7 5.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. On the forms, you must add "subscribers_only: true" to additional settings. Because this was not set, it was not allowing me to pull information from the current user, which was the reason it was not submitting to the database.